# How to xfpolt graphic in scilab

Tags: scilab

I try to fill up the graph between 1.5 to 4.5 but it still have some empty area.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB33I.png)
here is my function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajaax.png)

Comment: Can your give your code (edit your post) ?